How do I loop back to the beginning from the end of a list?
I have a list
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
I want to implement a Shift Cipher.
User input is a word and the number of places to shift.
Eg: If I choose the word hello and want a shift of 5, the new word would be mjqqt. The letter 'h' shifted by 5 letters becomes 'm', 'e' shifted by 5 letters becomes 'j' and so on.
I am able to do this as long as the
position of the original letter + shift amount is less than 26(len(alphabet)) at which point it reaches the end of the list and throws a list index out of range error.
So how do i get to continue counting from the beginning of the list after reaching the end.
Tried
new_letter = alphabet[len(alphabet) - (len(alphabet) - shift -1)]
which didnt give the correct letter after the shift

Maybe you need to use modulo keyword

please edit the question based on the question standards

Easy solution: do alphabet += alphabet after initializing the list, and you'll no longer get index errors (as long as the shift is no greater than the length of the alphabet, but there would be no point in using a shift that big).

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

As I understand it, you are trying to implement something like Caesar's cipher. To make it work correctly for both negative shifts and positive shifts, use modulo division. We need to find the index of the current character, add the shift and divide by the number of letters in your alphabet list. This will give you the index of the new character in the alphabet list. However, your description doesn't say anything now about if the character is not in your alphabet list, in that case I just leave the original character. Here is the code that shows how this can be done:
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase  # abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz


def encode_word_use_caesar_cipher(target_string: str, shift: int) -> str:
    result_symbols = []
    alphabet_length = len(alphabet)
    for symbol in target_string:
        #  if the symbol is not in the alphabet list, symbol_index = -1
        symbol_index = alphabet.find(symbol)
        result_symbols.append(
            symbol if symbol_index == -1
            else alphabet[(symbol_index + shift) % alphabet_length]
        )
    return ''.join(result_symbols)


print(encode_word_use_caesar_cipher('hello', 5))  # mjqqt
print(encode_word_use_caesar_cipher('hello', -5))  # czggj
print(encode_word_use_caesar_cipher('hello world', 5))  # mjqqt btwqi
print(encode_word_use_caesar_cipher('hello', 26 * 2))  # hello
print(encode_word_use_caesar_cipher('hello', -26 * 2))  # hello


Note it’s a bit confusing that result_string is not a string, but a list; especially given target_string is a string ;)

I agree with you. I've updated the code. It should be clearer.

As pointed out by @jasonharper in the comments, you can also concat the alphabet at the end of itself to avoid any issue with indexes.
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
alphabet_size = len(alphabet)
alphabet2 = alphabet + alphabet

Then ensure that the shift is smaller than the size of the alphabet, and you’re done:
def shift_word(word, n):
    # Account for large shifts (30 -> 4)
    n %= alphabet_size

    return "".join(
        alphabet2[alphabet2.index(letter)+n]
        for letter in word
    )

print(shift_word("".join(alphabet), 1))
# => "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"

print(shift_word("zaza", 100))
# => "vwvw"


You need to use a for-loop to iterate through the list alphabet. Use an if-statement to check if the new index (current_index+shift) is over the length of the alphabet list. If True, index the alphabet list by the new index minus length of list will do. The following code will address your problem:
def shift_word(character_list):
    l=character_list
    word, shift = input('enter word and shift amount; don\'t separate with comma').split(' ')
    shift = int(shift)
    res=''
    for t in word:
        ind = l.index(t)
        new = ind + shift
        if new >= len(l):
            char = l[new - len(l)]
        else:
            char = l[new]
        res += char
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':

    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 
                'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 
                'y', 'z']

    r=shift_word(alphabet)
    print(r)

Console output:
enter word and shift amount; don't separate with commahello 5
mjqqt

Process finished with exit code 0


Note: the code above is tested and executed in PyCharm Professional, Python 3.11.2. The code above should work fine in all Python 3 releases, though. Also, I think being able to change the character set every time is very convenient if you want different datasets; for example, if you want a words list someday. For this reason, I put the code inside a function that takes the character set as an argument.

Speaking about convenience, the function should do only one thing (shift the word, as its name says) and not take care of the input.

@bfontaine I agree that extensive I/O operations should be refactored into a separate function, especially when determining bottlenecks in performance. But in this case it is just a single input() call so I think it is OK. Also, the asker didn't asked for me to put it into a function, I just did it as an extra.

this is about writing composable code, not performance: the asker wants a function that shifts a word; I would expect a function that take the word as argument, so that I could use it from some other code (including unit tests). It's the caller's responsability to decide how they get the input. Imagine if instead of writing l.index(t) you had to write l.index(), which would then call input() to ask you what element you want the index of.
